# Android DataBinding with selector view

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to use selector with view (favorite button) and Data Binding library.
This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout ...>
<data>
    <variable
            name="obj"
            type="com.zor.dev.simplebelnewsreader.instance.News"/>

    <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.zor.dev.simplebelnewsreader.handler.Handlers"/>
</data>
<View
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/selectorButton"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.setFavorite(obj)}"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_button2"
            app:selected="@{obj.favorite}"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>
```

This is my `Handler`:

```
 public void setFavorite(News news) {
    news.setFavorite(!news.isFavorite());
}
```

and this is `selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
      android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_purple_a400_24dp"
      >
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_favorite_not">

</item>
```

And nothing, when i clicked item. What wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I only forget to set data and handler in my `Activity` when inflate `DataBinding` like this:

```
binding.setObj(data);
binding.setHandler(new Handlers());
```

Answer (score 0):

Xml:

```
<View
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/selectorButton"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.setFavorite(obj)}"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_button2"
            app:selected="@={obj.favorite}"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>
```

Handler:

```
public void setFavorite(News news) {
    news.setFavorite(!news.isFavorite());
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.favorite); //'favorite' is the boolean variable name
}
```

Comment: I use `BaseObservable` in my instance class, and this line no need